# Get the value bottommost TextView that add programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, sharedpreferences, textview

I am adding `TextView` programmatically on `LinearLayout` :

[image]

And then I `click` on a `TextView` and I pass `IDs` and `Texts` of TextView to another `Activity` (With `SharedPreferences`).

But when I get data from `SharedPreferences` in another activity and see data with `Log` I just get the `ID` and `Value` bottommost `TextView`.

(For example i just see the data of `TextView_3`).

But perhaps i had multiple `TextView` on `LinearLayout` and i click on 2nd `TextView` or another `TextView` but it just get me data of bottommost `TextView`.

```
public class ChatPage extends Activity {
TextView[] txt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_page);
          txt = new TextView[totalPersons];
          for (int s = 0; s < listOfPersons.getLength(); s++) {
              txt[s] = new TextView(ChatPage.this);
              if (group.equals("Admin")) {
                txt[s].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(
                                    ChatPage.this,
                                    ConversationPage.class));
                                    editor.putString("Adminid", id);
                                    editor.putString("NameAdmin", name);
                                    editor.commit();
                            }
                   });
              }
              if (group.equals("User")) {
                txt[s].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(
                                    ChatPage.this,
                                    ConversationPage.class));
                                    editor.putString("Userid", id);
                                    editor.putString("NameUser", name);
                                    editor.commit();
                            }
                   });
              }
          }
    }
}
```

Another `Activity` i get data :

```
UserID = (shared.getString("Userid", "NULLID"));
UserNAME = (shared.getString("NameUser", "NULLNAME"));

IDAdmin = (shared.getString("Adminid", "NULL_idSharee"));
AdminName = (shared.getString("NameAdmin", "NULL_NameSharee"));
Log.i("test", "UserID " + UserID );
Log.i("test", "UserNAME " + UserNAME );
Log.i("test", "IDAdmin " + IDAdmin );
Log.i("test", "AdminName " + AdminName );
```

Comment: where you setting ID to the textview ?

Comment: you should use settag() and gettag() while aadding view programatically

Comment: My code is huge but i get IDs from a xml string then i fetch that from xml then add it to editor.putString(...).

Comment: The problem is you are using listeners for all `TextView`s that do exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a java issue, you need to instantiate new class for each on click listener, you can't do in this way. create a private class in your code

```
 private class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    private final String    mId;

    public MyOnClickListener(String id) {
        mId= id;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ACtivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("current_post_id", mId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

then

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(id));
```

Comment: You're wrong, he is already instantiating by `new OnClickListener()`.

Comment: editor.putString("Userid", id);     i think that he's not declaring the id final, so he use every time the same variable, being overried and it saves the last value. For this reason you need the class, to have multiple instances of your id

Answer (score 1):

add your views like this:

```
final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yourLayout,
                yourLinearLayout, false);
        TextView text= (TextView ) view.findViewById(R.id.chapter_page);
        view.setTag(unique Id);//your TextView's id that later use in onClick
        text.setText(yourText);
        goToPage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                int id = (Integer) view.getTag();//this return clicked textView id
                //do some thing...
            }
        });

        yourLinearLayout.addView(view);
```

you can put this code in loop and add view to linearLayout more than one.

Answer (score 1):

you should provide a unique id to your text view like this

for an example

```
public void add_Text_view_row(String name,int i){
     TextView a = new TextView(getActivity());
        a.setText(name);


        a.setId(17*i);

        linearlayout_your.addView(a);

         a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // your codes should be here

        }
    });


}
```

you can use this method in side a loop.you should pass data to those parameters

Answer (score 1):

Your response is here :

```
///In your Oncreate
txt[s].setText(usename);
txt[s].setLayoutParams(params);
txt[s].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
txt[s].setClickable(true);
txt[s].setId(5*s);
txt[s].set

OnClickListener(new listen(s,idTwo,nameTwo));
    //----//
////And then create a class
public class listen implements OnClickListener{
    int bId;  
    String Pid;
    String Pname;
    listenSharee(int _id,String _Pid,String _Pname) {  
        bId = _id;  
        Pid = _Pid;
        Pname = _Pname;
    } 

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(ChatPage.this,YourClass.class));
        editor.putString("Aname", Pid);
        editor.putString("Aname", Pname);
        editor.commit();
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), txt[bId].getText()+ " * " + Pid + " * " + Pname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Good Luck. ;)